# pptpd: log of unsuccessful authentication

Tags: log-files, pptpd

I am using `pptpd` on Debian 6.
  I know that `last` shows the list of connections as well as the source IP.

I am looking for the log of unsuccessful authentication, or any form of alert/ban for a source IP failing to authenticate.

Is there anything that works with `pptpd`? or `wtmp`?
  Or should I look at external authentication mechanism (radius?) to get the logs I need.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you enable logwtmp option on your pptpd.conf, you should see on /var/log/messages

pptpd.conf

```
# TAG: logwtmp
#       Use wtmp(5) to record client connections and disconnections.
#
logwtmp
```

/var/log/messages

```
Mar 13 19:45:23 pineapple pppd[25571]: No CHAP secret found for authenticating USERNAME
Mar 13 19:45:23 pineapple pppd[25571]: Peer riqa failed CHAP authentication
Mar 13 19:45:24 pineapple pptpd[25570]: CTRL: EOF or bad error reading ctrl packet length.
Mar 13 19:45:24 pineapple pptpd[25570]: CTRL: couldn't read packet header (exit)
Mar 13 19:45:24 pineapple pptpd[25570]: CTRL: CTRL read failed
Mar 13 19:45:24 pineapple pppd[25571]: Modem hangup
Mar 13 19:45:24 pineapple pppd[25571]: Connection terminated.
Mar 13 19:45:24 pineapple pppd[25571]: Exit.
Mar 13 19:45:24 pineapple pptpd[25570]: CTRL: Client w.x.y.z control connection finished
```

Comment: Thanks Rikih. Would you know any good tool to automate an audit of the /var/log/messages?

Comment: you can try failtoban (http://www.fail2ban.org) or swatch  (http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/)